# Rails 3 autoloading with models in nested modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

We're in the process of making a major database change to our Rails application. In order to be able to interop with the existing code, my plan is to do all the work in module namespaces to keep them separate from the existing models. However, I'm running into Rails autoload problems.

My file structure is like:

```
app/
  models/
    entity/
      new_thing.rb
    old_thing.rb
```

Where new_think.rb contains something like

```
module Entity
  class NewThing
  end
end
```

and old_thing.rb contains something like

```
class OldThing
end
```

`OldThing` gets autoloaded fine, but I keep getting errors like this:

```
Expected app/models/entity/new_thing.rb to define NewThing
```

Is there a way I can get it to correctly expect entity/new_thing.rb to define `Entity::NewThing`?

Comment: Try adding a module outside the entity directory that requires all inside the respective directory.
Another way is to have a class that represents the super class of new entities. I usually do this second one for the api v1 namespace, using
class V1::Controller; as the classes name.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

In your old_thing.rb

```
class OldThing
  Extend Entity
end
```

or

```
class OldThing
  require "entity/new_thing"
end
```